# How to buy a home in halal way

Tags: halal-haram, riba

Assalamu Alaikum,

I knew in India all the bank giving a loan based on interest, Now a days buying a home without loan is difficult for upper class family itself. then how a middle class man buy a home in halal way.is there any way to get home loan without interest..? or is any other possible way is there

Comment: I don't know about India, but there are Islamic banks which offer services that you may consider. They buy the house and rent it to you, the ownership is divided into several small  shares which you buy from them slowly over a period of time until you own the whole house.

Comment: In India we don't have Islamic banks

Comment: [https://www.quora.com/How-many-Islamic-banks-are-there-in-India](https://www.quora.com/How-many-Islamic-banks-are-there-in-India)  and [https://www.globalbankingandfinance.com/list-of-islamic-banks-in-india/](https://www.globalbankingandfinance.com/list-of-islamic-banks-in-india/)

Comment: Many modern scholars consider buying by loan in non-Muslim countries as allowed under certain conditions.

Comment: @Medi1Saif can you give any reference link for that fatwa..?

Comment: No but I heard that Sheikh Yousuf al-Qaradawi and the scholars of al-Azhar hold this opinion. And so far I'm in doubt that any of the so called Islamic banks actually is Islamic, but that's my own opinion, based on more hearsay than actual knowledge.

Comment: Have you considered borrowing money from your relatives and friends? Perhaps you could borrow enough combined to buy the house.